# Pycharm: python not configured for tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

Im new to programming, Im doing a project and I am using Pycharm on my mac as my Ide. When I try to run my code I keep getting the same error. I have the future library but it doesn't seem to help.

```
 import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Comment: How exactly did you install Python?

Comment: I just use pycharm, I didn't actually install python. Im a beginner so i don't know much